# Some Bootstrap 4 classes don't work in my Angular 8 project

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

I am creating a header where the elements are supposed to be next to each other, but just one element appears in the browser and the others don't, and I wrote the code for them.

I came to the conclusion that the problem is the bootstrap classes I am using because when I inspected the elements in the browser, they appeared gray, like this: [image: like this]
I am using Bootstrap 4, my browser is Firefox and I am not an expert in Angular, so please be considerate.

**This is my HTML code**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Recipes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**And I added Bootstrap by installing it with npm and then adding this in the angular.json file**

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.css",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
```

Comment: This is probably because you didn't add the necessary `nav-item` class to your items in your navbar: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/

Comment: I added the class as you pointed out, but it didn't work.

Comment: Try adding a simpler bootstrap component. ex: <button class="btn btn-success">Hello</button> and see if it hooks on to bootstrap. If it does, it something with the nav. If its not bootstrap'ish then its something with the angular.json

Comment: I tried the button example, and it appears in the browser, so i guess is something with the nav

Comment: hmm I was messing around and decided to delete the collapse class and the items inside that div appeared, but under the Recipe Book title, like this: https://ibb.co/bKZmvkV The point of using the collapse class here is that the items end up next to each other, is there an alternate way of using collapse?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I fixed whatever was going on in my project's header. So, it turned out I didn't need to use these classes: navbar-default, navbar-header, collapse, navbar-collapse, and nav. Instead, i added these classes: navbar-expand-sm, bg-light, navbar-light, nav-item, nav-link. The code turned out like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light navbar-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Recipe Book</a>

    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Recipes</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Shopping List</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button">Manage</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Save Data</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Fetch Data</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

I read [the usage of the bootstrap navbar by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp)
This how the project looks so far, the header looks almost exactly like the instructor's, but I am satisfied with it. Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for the insight.
[image: final result]